# Embedded executable JS from Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to make embedded executable JS for other sites?

I have a Rails application (3000 port) in which:

> routes.rb

```
get '/embed/:tag_name',to: 'embed_widget#tag_name'
```

> embed_widget_controller.rb

```
class EmbedWidgetController < ApplicationController
  layout false, only: [:tag_name]
  protect_from_forgery except: [:tag_name]
  before_action :set_access_headers, only: [:tag_name]

  def tag_name
    @tag_name = params[:tag_name]
  end

  private

  def set_access_headers
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/javascript; charset=utf8'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  end
end
```

> tag_name.html.haml

```
:plain
  var tag = "#{@tag_name}"
  console.log('Hello from embedded JS. Tag name =', tag)
```

I am inserting code to connect JS on another site (3001 port):

```
<div class='embed'>
  <script src='http://localhost:3000/embed/exampletagname' type='text/javascript'></script>
</div>
```

But nothing happens.

How to get output to console on another site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code serves content type `text/html`, but for scripts it should be `text/javascript`

```rb
get '/embed/:tag_name',to: 'embed_widget#tag_name', defaults: {format: :js}
```

and rename your view to `tag_name.js.erb`:

```
var tag = "<%= @tag_name %>";
console.log('Hello from embedded JS. Tag name =', tag)
```

embed as previously, or via `http://localhost:3000/embed/exampletagname.js`

Comment: I did everything as you wrote. But still nothing is happening :с
In `tag_name.js.erb`, I left only `console.log('Hello from embedded JS')`

Comment: @RomanOks check if it renders correctly by directly requesting `curl -v http://localhost:3000/embed/exampletagname.js`, also check if the other site disables the script via CSP

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8`, `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, `< console.log('Hello from embed JS')`

Comment: I just tried to start another server (site) and it worked! Thanks.